# Set in javascript not working in IE11. Initialized to empty set

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am using set initialization with javascript using :

```
var set1 = new Set(["sumit","sumit","amit","anil","anish"]);
```

This set works in firefox and chrome, however the set1 value is not populated in set1. Looking in set1, I have empty set.

How to use set initailaization using javascript that works in IE11?

Comment: Transpile your ES6 method to ES5, or use an alternative method.

Comment: Not all features of sets are supported in IE 11 (in this case, `new Set(iterable)`), see [MDN Set browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility).